# CakePHP, working with HABTM tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working with CakePHP 2.x and I was wondering if there is any built-in functionality for working with HABTM join tables.  I don't really see anything in the documentation for directly changing the attributes of a HABTM relationship. This is what I mean:

I have a join table that contains flags for a relationship between two models that can be demonstrated as such:

```
(int) id | (int) user_id | (int) video_id | (bool) hasRated | (bool) hasWatched | (bool) hasDownloaded
```

The first column is just the regular table id.  The next two (user_id and video_id) are the typical HABTM foreign keys to the user table and video table.  The following 3 flags are indicators of the relationship between the two models (has this video been watched? has it been rated? etc.)

I am currently building my own queries and this is my boot-strap setup.  My end goal is to add attributes between the relationship of two models.  Is this the correct way to approach this, or is there a more Cakey way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka.

In 2.x, cake will automagically create a model for you and recognize the relationship.

`$this->Video->UserVideo` will generate a model that fits the HABTM join table `users_videos`.  You can then interact with it just like a regular model and it will update the database.

Answer (score 0):

For maintain a `HABTM` you can maintain join table. The cake convention for join table for `HABTM` is:

> This new join table's name needs to include the names of both models
>   involved, in alphabetical order, and separated with an underscore ( _
>   ). The contents of the table should be two fields, each foreign keys
>   (which should be integers) pointing to both of the primary keys of the
>   involved models. To avoid any issues - don't define a combined primary
>   key for these two fields, if your application requires it you can
>   define a unique index. If you plan to add any extra information to
>   this table, it's a good idea to add an additional primary key field
>   (by convention 'id') to make acting on the table as easy as any other
>   model.

So its seems just fine for you. But you must follow the naming convention.

For more detail see [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM).

Comment: As you can see, I already follow the naming convention. I have no problem establishing the HABTM relationship described in the cake docs, I just want to use the relationship to become more descriptive (hasRated, hasWatched, etc.) and was wondering if cake had, for instance, a find way to update the relationship itself.